# Why is there sometimes undefined in my tab?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random, passwords

I did random password generator and it works fine but sometimes when I roll for new pass there is undefined inside var text in console. How to fix it?

```js
function generate()
{
    var tab = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
    var text = [];


    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        x = Math.random()*tab.length;
        z = Math.round(x)
        text.push(tab[z]);
    }
    console.log(text);
    document.getElementById('input1').value = text.join('');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<head></head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="randompass">
    <input id="input1"></input>
    <button onclick="generate()">Create random</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `tab[tab.length]`?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `Math.floor()` instead of `Math.round` - You can end up picking `tab.length + 1` sometimes when using `Math.round` because of rounding upwards

```js
function generate() {
  var tab = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
  var text = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    x = Math.random() * tab.length;
    z = Math.floor(x)
    text.push(tab[z]);
  }
  console.log(text);
  document.getElementById('input1').value = text.join('');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="randompass">
    <input id="input1">
    <button onclick="generate()">Create random</button>
  </div>
</body>
```